# DC adapter not supplying current

Tags: current, dc, adapter

I'm trying to get .5 A of current from a mobile phone's DC adapter, which is within its rated specifications.  I am able to detect a voltage of ~5 V DC between the power and ground wires, so it seems like the adapter's working.  However, when I apply a load between the two wires, I can't detect any current flowing with my multimeter (it's set to mA, and the terminals are in the correct sockets).  I've tried putting a rheostat in between (from 0-1 megaohms) the two wires, as well as a very fine nichrome (resistance) wire - no current flows in either case.  Am I doing something wrong, or does the cell phone charger have some sort of safety mechanism built in that prevents it from supplying current to only the phone?

thanks

Comment: Are you using the multimeter in series with your circuit? (just checking :) )

Comment: Did you put the ammeter directly across the 5 volts and not in series with the circuit? If so, you may have blown the internal fuse of the meter by feeding to much current.

Comment: MOST meters will blow their mA range fuse if shorted across a power supply.

Answer (score 3):

As others suggest, you may have done violence to your metre fuse.
MOST meters will blow their mA range fuse if shorted across a power supply.

Connect, say, 47R across 5V supply.
Measure the voltage.
If the voltage is still about 5V, the supply is just about OK.

- I = V/R
- I = 5/47 ~=  106 mA.
  Enough for  a test.
- Power = V<sup>2</sup>/R = 5 x 5 / 47
  -~~ 0.5 wATTS.
  Use 1W

Or use a smaller still resistor to get larger test currents - but 47R should be enough to check.

Comment: Take care with smaller resistors - the wattage will go up quickly, in order to test your 500mA, you would need a resistor that can dissipate 2.5W (which is quite a lot for a resistor) - you could probably get by with a 2W resistor for a short time to do a test, but it would warm up quickly.

Answer (score 2):

A load resistance of 10Ω should draw 0.5A of current from the supply.

That would dissipate 2.5W of power, so a nice big power resistor would be required.

When measuring the current you want to measure the current *through* the resistor, not the voltage *across* the resistor.  Make sure your ammeter is in series with the resistor (and connected the right way round):

```
(+)----(A)---/\/\/\---,
               10Ω    |
(-)-------------------'
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget the meter.  You may have blown its fuse as others have said, and it's also not clear how you were connecting it.

At 5V and 500mA max, a 10 Ω resistor is the smallest load resistance within the supply's rating according to what you have said.  That will dissipate (V^^2)/R = 25/R = 2.5W.  2.5W will be very obvious.  Anything short of a 6 inch long wire wound resistor will heat up easily.  2.5W is enough to blow up a common 1/4W leaded resistor, or at least make it snap, crackle, and pop, and emit noxious fumes.  A 2W resistor will get too hot to hold in a couple of seconds.

You don't need exactly 10Ω for this trick.  That is the minimum resistance and therefore the maximum power.  Just 1/4W thru a 1/4W resistor will make it quite toasty, probably too hot to hold after a few seconds.  100mW thru a small resistor will heat it noticeably.  To get 1/4W you need a 25 / (1/4) = 100Ω resistor, and 250Ω will dissipate 100mW.